# Not able to store image name in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the requirement where image is uploaded and randomly generated id store in the database, i m not able to save it in database and image in folder .
this is code i have written ,i want randomly generated id to store in database and image in local folder

controller

```
function add(){
        if($this->session->userdata('user_id'))
        {  
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('pp_image','Image','required');
            if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
            {  
                    if($_FILES["pp_image"]["type"] != "image/jpg" && $_FILES["pp_image"]["type"] != "image/png" && $_FILES["pp_image"]["type"] != "image/jpeg"
                     && $_FILES["pp_image"]["type"] != "image/gif" ) {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid Image');
                        redirect('setting/add');
                    }
                $result_data = $this->Home_model->add($_FILES);
                if($result_data)
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success','image Added Successfully');

                }
            }
            else
            {
                $data['_view'] = 'home/add';
            }
        }
        else{
            redirect('admin');
        }
    }
```

and this model

```
function add($image){

       $image_details = array(
           "created_on" => time()
       );
       $this->db->insert('home',$logo_details);
        if(isset($image['pp_image']) && $image['pp_image']['name'] != "")
        {   
            $dir = FCPATH."resources/images/logo/";

            if($image["pp_image"]["type"] == "image/jpg" || $image["pp_image"]["type"] == "image/png" || $image["pp_image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"
            || $image["pp_image"]["type"] == "image/gif" ) { 
                $hash  = md5(rand(1, 1000000).time()).'.jpg';
                if(!is_dir($dir))
                {
                    @mkdir($dir, 0777);
                }
                if(move_uploaded_file($image["pp_image"]["tmp_name"], $dir.$hash))
                {
                    $array['image'] = $hash;
                    $this->db->update('home',$array);
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
   }
```

and this the view part

```
<form role="form" id="logo-form" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group<?php echo form_error('pp_image') ? "has-error" : "" ?>">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="form-field-1">
                             Image : 
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="file" name="pp_image">
                             <?php if (form_error('pp_image')) {
                                ?>
                                <?php echo form_error('pp_image') ?> 
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" style="background-color:#16a085; color:white; font-weight:bold;">
                        </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: @LozCherone i forgot to comment out here i was just checking if i m getting data or not.

Comment: try CI way http://weblint4u.com/upload-files-in-codeigniter/

Comment: Where specifically does it fail?  Is the file not saved to the file system?  Is the record not saved to the database?  Is the model's function invoked at all?

Comment: @David not able to save in folder and also not in db

Comment: Could you put log and/or error messages to understand the problem ?

Comment: @itsoftware: Right, but "it doesn't work" isn't really meaningful debugging information.  *Where* does it fail?  What part of it *does* work?  Are there any errors in the PHP logs?  When you debug through it, what happens?

Comment: Just a suggestion, a cleaner way to test the mime type would be storing the authorized mime types in an array and then in the if checking with the `in_array` function. note that mime type is not so secure it can be manipulated by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off the form validation does not work with $_FILES only $_POST. You should use the CI upload class which will also allow you to better validate image types. Currently you are doing the image type validation twice - once in the controller and once in the model. This is probably not required.

Change your controller function to something like this:

```
function add(){
    if($this->session->userdata('user_id'))
    { 
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH."resources/images/logo/";
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']    = '100';//eg
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';//eg
    $config['max_height']  = '768';//eg
    $config['file_name']  = $your_random_file_name;
    //more config - 

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('pp_image'))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid Image');
        redirect('setting/add');
    } else {

        //just pass your new filename & path to your model to go in the db
        $this->your_model->add($your_random_file_name);
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: i m getting error as Undefined property: Setting::$validation

Comment: Ah sorry you dont need the validation library as your setting your own flash data. Edited the answer